# How to disable show selected items using package MultiSelectDialogField in fluttter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using this package

```
  multi_select_flutter: ^4.1.3
```

When I select a dropdown, all the items are displayed in a popup window. And when I select items, those selected items are shown in the UI.

**popup window**

[image]

selected items

[image]

I want to disable the display of selected items on the screen, but it's okay for the popup window to show the selected items. Actually, that's the only place where I want them to be displayed as selected items.

code

```
     Container(
                        height: height * 0.07,
                        child: MultiSelectDialogField<String>(
                          title: Text('Select your pet allergies'),
                          items: allergies
                              .map((allergy) => MultiSelectItem<String>(allergy, allergy))
                              .toList(),
                          listType: MultiSelectListType.CHIP,

                          onConfirm: (List<String> values) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedAllergies = values;
                            });
                          },
                          chipDisplay: null,

                        ),
                      ),
```

```
List<String> allergies = [
  'Animal Allergy',
  'Drug Allergy',
  'Environmental Allergy',
  'Food Allergy',
  'Pollen Allergy',
  'Miscellaneous Allergy',
  'Miscellaneous Contraindication',
  'Plant Allergy'
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
`chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay.none()`